# core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: global is not defined ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: ionic3

core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: global is not defined
ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
    at Object../node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js (index.js:2)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
    at Object../node_modules/request/lib/helpers.js (helpers.js:5)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
    at Object../node_modules/request/index.js (index.js:19)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
    at Object../node_modules/woocommerce-api/index.js (index.js:3)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)